# 'The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type' error occurs when executing 'make' for Apache 2.4.54 in IBM AIX 7.1

Tags: apache, makefile, websphere, aix

I'm trying to compile and install 'Apache 2.4.54 64bit' in 'IBM AIX 7.1'.

When I execute 'make', I hit this 'The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type'  error.

```
$ oslevel -s
7100-05-01-1731
$ cc -qversion
IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V16.1.0  (5725-C72, 5765-J12)
Version: 16.01.0000.0007
$ make
Making all in srclib
Making all in apr
        /bin/sh /refresh/home/stage/apache/2.4.54/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=compile cc -qlanglvl=extc89 -g   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -U__STR__ -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE   -I./include -I/refresh/home/stage/apache/2.4.54/srclib/apr/include/arch/unix -I./include/arch/unix -I/refresh/home/stage/apache/2.4.54/srclib/apr/include/arch/unix -I/refresh/home/stage/apache/2.4.54/srclib/apr/include -I/refresh/home/stage/apache/2.4.54/srclib/apr/include/private -I/refresh/home/stage/apache/2.4.54/srclib/apr/include/private  -o atomic/unix/builtins64.lo -c atomic/unix/builtins64.c && touch atomic/unix/builtins64.lo
"atomic/unix/builtins64.c", line 33.12: 1506-754 (S) The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type.
"atomic/unix/builtins64.c", line 38.5: 1506-754 (S) The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type.
"atomic/unix/builtins64.c", line 43.12: 1506-754 (S) The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type.
"atomic/unix/builtins64.c", line 48.12: 1506-754 (S) The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type.
"atomic/unix/builtins64.c", line 54.12: 1506-754 (S) The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type.
"atomic/unix/builtins64.c", line 61.12: 1506-754 (S) The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.
$
```

And this is the source of "builtins64.c".

```
   +31  APR_DECLARE(apr_uint64_t) apr_atomic_add64(volatile apr_uint64_t *mem, apr_uint64_t val)
   +32  {
   +33      return __sync_fetch_and_add(mem, val);
   +34  }
   +35
   +36  APR_DECLARE(void) apr_atomic_sub64(volatile apr_uint64_t *mem, apr_uint64_t val)
   +37  {
   +38      __sync_fetch_and_sub(mem, val);
   +39  }
   +40
   +41  APR_DECLARE(apr_uint64_t) apr_atomic_inc64(volatile apr_uint64_t *mem)
   +42  {
   +43      return __sync_fetch_and_add(mem, 1);
   +44  }
   +45
   +46  APR_DECLARE(int) apr_atomic_dec64(volatile apr_uint64_t *mem)
   +47  {
   +48      return __sync_sub_and_fetch(mem, 1);
   +49  }
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use option `-q64` or set `OBJECT_MODE=64` environment variable?

Comment: Thank you. As you said, 'export OBJECT_MODE=64' resolves the problem. I appreciate for your help.